# Problem Evaluating a Combinatorics Problem - answer not matching the book

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem:
Given
\begin{eqnarray*}
p &=& \frac{{6 \choose 4}{5 \choose 3}}{{11 \choose 7} } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
What is the value of p?
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
{6 \choose 4} &=& \frac{6(5)}{2} = 15 \\
{5 \choose 3} &=& \frac{5(4)}{2} = 10 \\
{11 \choose 7} &=& \frac{11(10)(9)(8)}{4(3)(2)} = \frac{11(10)(9)(2)} {3(2)} \\
{11 \choose 7} &=& 11(10)(3) \\
p &=& \frac{ 15(10)}{ 11(10)(3)} = \frac{15}{11(3)} \\
p &=& \frac{5}{11} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
However, the book gets $\frac{5}{7}$. I am wondering if the book is wrong or if I did something wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((6+choose+4)(5+choose+3))%2F(11+choose+7). Looks like you got the same thing, so where is the issue?

Comment: Looks like you both got $\frac{5}{11}$, so the problem is ...?

Comment: If the book says 5/7 it likely has a typo. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{{6 \choose 4}{5 \choose 3}}{{11 \choose 7} } = \frac{\frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{5!}{3!2!}}{\frac{11!}{7!4!}} = \frac{\frac{6\times 5}{2}\frac{5 \times 4}{2}}{\frac{11\times10\times9\times8}{4\times3\times2}} = \frac{6\times5\times5\times4}{4}\left(\frac{4\times3\times2}{11\times10\times9\times8}\right)=\frac{2^6\times3^2\times5^2}{2^6\times3^2\times5\times11}=\frac{5}{11}$$